# Query using HAVING with multiple conditions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

For example, there is a table with the properties of the goods. Each product can have multiple values ​​of the same properties.

Goods

```
goods_id | property | value  

1        |color     | red  
1        |size      | 100  
1        |size      | 200  
2        |color     | red  
2        |color     | green  
2        |size      | 200
```

If I need to find all the items whith a color **red** AND a size of **100**, then I run this query:

```
SELECT goods_id FROM goods
WHERE (property = 'color' AND value = 'red') OR
      (property = 'size' AND value = '100')
GROUP BY goods_id
HAVING COUNT(goods_id) = 2
```

MYSQL returns the goods_id = 1

But if I need to find all the items with a color **red OR green** AND a size of **100**, the following query

```
SELECT goods_id FROM goods
WHERE (property = 'color' AND value IN ('red', 'green')) OR
      (property = 'size' AND value = '100')
GROUP BY goods_id
HAVING COUNT(goods_id) = 2
```

returns the ids 1 AND 2, but should only 1.
How can I change the second query to return the correct result? Thanks for any advice

Comment: What result by the way do you expect? Kindly post also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HAVING condition to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your Table:

```
goods_id | property | value
  1       |    color    | red
  1       |    size      | 100
  1       |    size      | 200
  2       |    color    | red
  2       |    color    | green
  2       |    size      | 200
```

And this is your first query:

```
  SELECT goods_id FROM goods
  WHERE (property = 'color' AND value = 'red') OR
  (property = 'size' AND value = '100')
  GROUP BY goods_id
  HAVING COUNT(goods_id) = 2
```

Without the `HAVING` clause first and only the `WHERE` statement you will have the result:

```
  1       |    color    | red
  1       |    size      | 100
  2       |    color    | red
```

But with the HAVING clause now since you want only goods_id having a count of 2 then what remains are:

```
  1       |    color    | red
  1       |    size      | 100
```

And since you group it only the `1` remains since you display the `goods_id`.

Now, on your second query you have:

```
 SELECT goods_id FROM goods
 WHERE (property = 'color' AND value IN ('red', 'green')) OR
  (property = 'size' AND value = '100')
 GROUP BY goods_id
 HAVING COUNT(goods_id) = 2
```

Based on the criteria again without the `HAVING` clause you want `property` of `color` and with value of either (that means OR) `red` or `green` OR `property` of `size` and `value` of `100`. So, you will get the result of:

```
goods_id | property | value
  1       |    color    | red
  1       |    size      | 100
  2       |    color    | red
  2       |    color    | green
```

And with the `HAVING` clause of `COUNT(goods_id)=2` naturally the two `goods_id` of `1` and `2` will result.

In other words the query result is **right**.

So, if you want only one result then you could probably use

```
LIMIT 1
```

Or probably your query is wrong and therefore you need to change a portion of it.

Comment: Your solution is the only special case which I have described. But if the product with id=2 would have a property size = 100, that a request should return goods_id 1 and 2. But anyway thanks for the query analysis